# How can i store data from react-hook-forms in cookies?

Tags: reactjs, forms, cookies

**In this case i need to store these datas in cookies but i dont know how to do it.**

Its already stored in *localStorage* but i need to store in the cookies too.

There is some library to do it? How can i use it?

Could someone help me, pls?

```
const Form = () => {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
        setValue,
    } = useForm({
        resolver: yupResolver(validationPost),
    });

    //API Handler
    const checkCEP = (e) => {
        if(!e.target.value)return;

        const cep = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, "");
        fetch(` https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/`).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {console.log(data);
        setValue('address', data.logradouro);
        setValue('city', data.localidade);
        setValue('state', data.uf);
    
    })

    };

    // LocalStorage
    const localStorageData = (data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("form", JSON.stringify(data))
        alert('You have been registered!')

        
    };

    return (
        <FormWrapper>
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(localStorageData)}>
                <div className="fields">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="name" {...register("name")} />
                        <p className="error-message">{errors.name?.message}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="fields">
                    <label>Date of birth</label>
                    <div>
                        <input type="date" name="birthdate" {...register("birthdate")} />
                        <p className="error-message">{errors.birthdate?.message}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Register" className="button-submit" />
            </form>
        </FormWrapper>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`set()` method from the cookies API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/cookies/set).

You will need to fulfill some requirements to use it, but those are laid out in the second paragraph of the above documentation link.

> The call succeeds only if you include the "cookies" API permission in your manifest.json file, as well as host permissions for the given URL specified in its manifest. The given URL also needs the necessary permissions to create a cookie with the given parameters.

In your case, once you have the above accounted for, it can be as easy as:

```
await browser.cookies.set({
  title: "Data Cookie ",
  url: "https://yoursite.com",
  value: data
});
```

As far as which values to add for all the optional properties, I love this ["cookie recipe" video by Google's Rowan Merewood](https://youtu.be/Fet6-IiX69E)